# create a xml string to be interpreted by Dom document

Tags: php, xml, parsing, domdocument

I have an XML file that is obtained via FTP using `fopen()` or `file_get_contents()`. I need to upload it to a DOM document with `$dom->loadXML()` but this only accepts XML strings in this format:

```
   <?php
 $string = <<<XML
    <?xml version='1.0'?> 
    <document>
     <title>/title>
     <from></from>
     <to></to>
     <body>

     </body>
    </document>
    XML;
?>
```

How I can convert the file I get for ftp, to this type of string?

Comment: This is a PHP script, not a XML file. The Heredoc syntax is broken, (The closing `XML;` has to be at the start of the line.) The XML string inside is broken, too. The closing tag for `title` is missing the `<`.

Comment: @JairoRamos We can't possibly tell you that unless you post a sample of the text  you're retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

Save your file in a specific folder, and use simplexml_load_string instead. Do check your XML, it looks like there is something wrong with it

```
$file_url = '';   //this is your file URL 

//if you are getting the file from the internet, it is best to use cURL to fetch the data, you can add additional code to control it. Otherwise if it is inside your project just use file_get_contents.

$xml_string = file_get_contents($file_url);

$xml   = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);
```

*UPDATING ANSWER BASED ON YOUR COMMENT*

You need to consider the:

- what is the size of the file?(9MB)

If your server has high and unlimited bandwidth, then 9MB should not be a problem, but you do need to consider the server where the XML reside if it can support high speed upload, otherwise your page might load quite slowly.

- how often do you access the file?

If you are accessing it all the time for all the pages, it is best to download it, but do take consideration if the data inside the files changes from time to time.

- does the data inside the file changes?

If the data does not change frequently, it is best to download it and save it as a file inside your project. Otherwise, you might want to create a php script to download the file, create a shell script to run the php script, then a CRON JOB to get the updated file, this is quite advance though.

I remember when I was developing a part of my previous project where as I need to have all the airports loaded from an XML(448KB) when the the transaction page renders, and because the list of airports around the world is too long, I downloaded the list of airport and just save it in our server. I did not make any additional php script and shell script to check the content of data because whenever the user was not able to find the corresponding airport they can report it and the developer can just have it updated manually considering the airport list does not change everyday.

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR COMMENT**

What I would recommend if that is the case:

- you can either create a table(easier) or a file where you will store the information whether the XML has been retrieved or not that day,
- when the page loads, check the table/file if the XML has been retrieved for today, if the XML has not been retrieved, get the XML file, save it in your server, then update the table/file so that it will indicate that it has been updated. **you do need to take into consideration that there might be several concurrent user or doing the same thing, so you need to take this into consideration and add additional confirmation/notification**
- after saving the latest copy of the file in your server, just do your regular parsing.
- finish your page load

You might want to clarify your question and list them.

Comment: that way I can save the file in my current folder. using fopen or file_get_contents ()

Comment: what is your question? do you want to save the file into your folder? You said you have an xml file obtained from FTP. can you please clarify your question.

Comment: my question is: how should I do for the xml file I get for ftp can be loaded to a DOM document?. I have to first download it to a local folder? I can do it without downloading it? xml file is 9MB

Comment: There are several approach to solve this kind of problem, but you do need to consider several things. 

Does the data inside the xml change from time to time? How often?

If yes, you cannot download it because it is better to retrieve it from the source otherwise the content is not up to date/correct


If the data does not change(such as xml containing country code) and if you access it all the time or most of the time?

If your answer is yes, you might want to download the XML and store it in your project as an external file. this is to save server resources such as bandwidth

Comment: xml file I get for ftp changes daily, as would be the code to obtain a file handle and DOM